# Storing the absolute value of an eigen vector in to variable

Tags: c++, eigen, pow

I seem to have problem with a silly problem as storing a the absolute value of Eigen vector3d.

I want to compute the `pow(p.cwiseAbs(),2)` but since `p.cwiseAbs()` isn't a double, the function call doesn't work.  i then tried to store it into a variable ..  but somehow it doesn't seem possible..

ex.

```
double p_abs = p.cwiseAbs();
```

Error message:

```
 error: cannot convert ‘const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs_op<double>, const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> >’ to ‘double’ in initialization
     double p_abs  = p.cwiseAbs();
```

How do i compute the `pow(..,2)` of the absolute value of the vector?.

The expression i am trying to write into code is :

The expression i am trying to code is the one explained by the first answer on this post.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784106/how-do-i-compute-the-closest-points-on-a-sphere-given-a-point-outside-the-sphere/1784159#1784159

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Compiler error? Incorrect value in the variable? Or what?

Comment: Judging by the documentation, this might be type mismatch. Are you sure the return value of `cwiseAbs` can be converted to a `double`? Does `auto p_abs = p.cwiseAbs();` work?

Comment: Not until you tell us what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Sorry `auto` works., but  still not able to `pow(auto,2)`

Comment: Like the name says, `cwiseAbs` returns a vector containing the absolute value of each component (cwise = component wise). You were probably looking for `Norm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the original question "how-do-i-compute-the-closest-points-on-a-sphere-given-a-point-outside-the-sphere" using Eigen:

```
Vector3d center, P, Q;
double radius;
Q = center + radius * (P-center).normalized()
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do i compute the pow(..,2) of the absolute value of the vector?

You are probably looking for the squared norm. That is simply:

```
p.squaredNorm();
```

Comment: Rather the square root of the squared norm.